# Are (x % y) and (x & (y-1)) equivalent?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I think calculating x % y is equivalent of x & (y-1), but when I try

```
if (x % y == x & (y-1)) {
    ...
}
```

I always get false unless using `(int)(x & (y-1))` instead.
This might be because of the return type for "bit-wise and". But after searching in google I didn't find much info about what type of data you get after `&`.
Can anyone help to explain a little bit?

EDIT: x and y are both integer types and y is a power of 2.

Comment: They are not equivalent. Try it out on paper yourself and you'll see immediately that it won't produce the same results.

Comment: Are you asking exclusively about `y` which are powers of 2?

Comment: @StereoBucket Don't you think that for special cases the two epressions are equivalent?

Comment: @Yunnosch you're correct. The question should've mentioned that tho.

Comment: The behavior will depend on exact types of `x` and `y`. Why is this critical information absent from the question?

Comment: "x and y are both integer types"  is still not enough. With operations like that you can easily run into behavior that depends on signedness and integral promotions.

Comment: @Yunnosch: When expressions are only "equivalent for special cases", then they are not equivalent at all. "Equivalent" wouldn't be the right word to use to describe it.

Comment: @AnT Sorry for not expressing my question clearly. y should always be a power of 2. At first I thought this was true for all integer y.

Comment: @AnT Strictly speaking you are right. But, as OP happens to have demonstrated by comment, not all terms in questions are used in the strict sense. In order to find out the actual question, it is necessary to look "around" the strict definition of used terms. I.e. I have asked about the restriction to powers of two, precisely because of being aware of the strict definition of "equivalent" and of the probability that it is not the meaning OP is thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the result is determined by the usual arithmetic rules (the same as for `+`, for instance) but this is not your issue here.

You might want to have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
7   == !=   For relational = and ≠ respectively
8   &   Bitwise AND
```

So putting `(x & (y - 1))` in parentheses would be enough, even without typecasting.

But please note that the result of your comparison is only true when `y` is a power of 2.

Is it `y` was a power of 2 in your tests? Then, your compiler treated that statement as, with extra parentheses—due to operator precedence—

```
if(((x % y) == x) & (y - 1)) {
```

With typecasting, you've got the correct expression

```
if((x % y) == (x & (y - 1))) {
```

and that was true, if `y` in binary was a single 1 followed by a few 0s.

Comment: You need to spend more words on explanation to make this a good answer, but you are close.

Comment: I did it even before your comment! 8-)

Comment: I saw a notification while I was typing, and, when done editing, found out it was your comment about extra. :)

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much!!!! I spent nearly a whole morning to debug this...

Answer (score 1):

The resulting type of the expression does not matter here. Both operands either are widened to `int` or `unsigned int`, or if either operand has higher rank than `int`, then promoted to the rank of the wider operand. None of this changes the results.

However, this is a precedence issue. `&` has counter-intuitively **lower** precedence than `==` because it was **also** originally used as the [boolean logic operator within `if` statements](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html). The *precedence* of `&` has regrettably stayed the same ever since.

Therefore your expression reads as if written

```
((x % y) == x) & (y - 1)
```

Since you're presumably testing with `y` < `x`, then `x % y` cannot be equal to `x`, therefore the left-hand side evaluates to 0, and that bitwise-anded with *any* values will always result in 0, therefore false.

---

If you parenthesize correctly,

```
(x % y) == (x & (y - 1))
```

the equivalence will hold true for all non-negative x if y is a positive power of 2. (1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...)

Comment: I deleted my comment under the OP, because I went wrong. This answer reminds me to a simple rule: "If unsure about  operator precedence use parenthesis!" If you think they might be needed, place them! Every reader will thank you for clarification.